# "It's just rammed up again"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, british-english

I heard in a British show this line:

> We cleared this place out before, but it's just **rammed up** again. ([source](https://youtu.be/qK80IpD50-8?t=1913))

The subtitles on Netflix also give "rammed up", but this phrase doesn't make sense to me stand-alone or in this context. "Ram" suggests a forceful collision or banging. "It (the place) has rammed up" sounds nonsensical. For a moment I thought it might be "ramped up", but it doesn't seem likely.

I've put up a link to the series on YouTube. What does "ram up" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ram in this sense means to *Cram* or *Stuff*

So it is saying that they emptied the tenement once, but now it has been *rammed/crammed/stuffed* back in (full to bursting)

[Source (click see more)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rammed)

> to cram; stuff:
>   *They rammed the gag in his mouth.*

Comment: +1 The link you've provided doesn't seem to have this usage though. The meaning of the sentence seemed clear, but I had never heard rammed used this way.

Comment: @Eddie Kal it is there, you just need to click *see more*

Comment: Found it. I included that entry in your answer. Hope you don't mind. I still can't help but wonder if it is fair to assume this is predominantly a BrE usage.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to BrE speakers who have commented/written answers. I think it's now safe to say this sense of rammed as "crammed, packed" is indeed a Britishism. I couldn't find anything in dictionaries touching "rammed up", but there is one entry on "rammed":

> **UK INFORMAL**
>
> very full or crowded:
>
> *On the trip back the train was rammed and I couldn't find a seat.
>
>   It's a beautiful city but it's rammed with tourists.* ([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rammed))

Comment: It has nothing to do with UK English specifically. It's just as common in [US English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ram#h2).

Comment: @JasonBassford Point taken about its occurrence in AmE, though I am not quite sure about "just as common". I went through every single indexed page from the first two pages of Google search results for ["the room was rammed"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+room+was+rammed%22). Out of a total of 19 pages: 1 link rot; 1 book by a South African writer; 1 book by NK writer/UK translator; 1 social media account of someone seemingly based in NYC; 1 Australian news piece; and the rest appear to be of/from the UK, I count 14 give or take.

Comment: Interestingly "building is rammed up" (https://www.google.com/search?q="buliding+is+rammed+up") appears as lyrics in a song feat Busta Rhymes by Tiësto

Comment: @Smock Hmm, interesting. I looked it up, and the lines go "_Everybody in the place stand up/And jump it, shake it, rush the club/Till the whole entire building is rammed up/And there’s nothing you can do to hold ‘em off_". Sounds to me like the rapper is talking about [bringing the house down](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+down+the+house) rather than having the house packed.

Comment: @EddieKal Yes - I wonder if there's another meaning attached to specifically 'rammed **up**' as a phrase, as opposed to being *rammed* in the *upwards/inwards* direction. Although I still think the meaning in the OP is about being crammed in.